# Graphviz draw tile with different cell colour and length

Tags: graphviz

How to represent this in a dot file?

[image]

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.
Please take the [tour] to learn how Stack Overflow works and read [ask] on how to improve the quality of your question.
Then check the [help/on-topic] to see which questions are on-topic on this site.
Please show your attempts you have tried and the problems/error messages you get from your attempts.

Comment: Look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70487546/how-to-make-this-graph-with-graphviz

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
digraph structs {
    node1 [shape=plaintext,
    label = <<table border="0" cellspacing="0">
          <tr>
          <td width="20">0</td>
          <td width="20">1</td>
          <td width="20">2</td>
          <td width="20">3</td>
          <td width="20">4</td>
          <td width="20">5</td>
          <td width="20">6</td>
          <td width="20">7</td>
          <td width="20">8</td>
          <td width="20">9</td>
          <td width="20">10</td>
          <td width="20">11</td>
          <td width="20">12</td>
          <td width="20">13</td>
          <td width="20">14</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td border="1" colspan="3" bgcolor="yellow">A</td>
            <td border="1" colspan="1" bgcolor="white"></td>
            <td border="1" colspan="1" bgcolor="white"></td>
            <td border="1" colspan="1" bgcolor="white"></td>
            <td border="1" colspan="2" bgcolor="pink">B</td>
            <td border="1" colspan="1" bgcolor="white"></td>
            <td border="1" colspan="2" bgcolor="green">C</td>
            <td border="1" colspan="4" bgcolor="#40e0d0">D</td>
          </tr>
          </table>>
  ];
}
```

[image]